# В чем заключаются логарифмический и константный алгоритмы поиска по базе данных через язык C++?

Tags: c++, база-данных, алгоритм, файлы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать алгоритм поиска по базе данных, используя только сторонние файлы, без массивов и других структур языка(не линейно). Знаю, что есть такие алгоритмы, как логарифмический и константный, но не знаю, в чём они заключаются и как реализуются.

Comment: Такие ответы читать больнее

Comment: Как-то очень непонятно написано. Что вы называете "базой данных"? Почему вы хотите использовать дополнительные файлы, а не "массивы и другие структуры языка"? Почему подписано "не линейно", вы думаете что используя массивы и "другие структуры" у вас всегда будет линейная сложность?.. *"есть такие алгоритмы, как логарифмический и константный"* Это не конкретные алгоритмы, а указание на скорость работы алгоритма.

Comment: Ограничения работы такие - нельзя массивы

Answer (score 1):

вам тут в 2х словах не объяснить, но можно чуть-чуть намекнуть :)

смотрите - скажем вы храните телефонные номера

если вы отсортируете номера по возрастанию, то определить, есть ли телефон в базе можно за O(log(N)) времени используя бинарный поиск (для 4 миллиардов чисел вам потребуется всего максимум 32 операции обращения к таблице, а для миллиона чисел - 20 операций)

если же вам нужен не конкретно телефонный номер, а узнать страну (первые 1-2 цифры номера), то все номера можно разбить на 100 групп и база будет содержать только 100 ячеек со значениями 0/1 - есть номер или нет номера

тогда для того, чтобы узнать есть ли у страны телефонные номера вам достаточно сразу обратиться к ячейке №N (первые 2 цифры) - это потребуется константное время O(1), т.е. 1 обращение к таблице

Когда в таблице хранятся не числа, а сложные данные, то используется хэширование - по сложным данные вычисляется некоторое значение (число), которое опять же можно отсортировать и искать данные бинарным поиском за O(log(N)) времени

Например, вам надо найти в таблице некоторый текст.

По каждому тексту вычисляется хэш-сумму (например CRC32 или MD5) и в таблице хранятся индексы - связка Hash:Index - хэш и указатель на данные соответствующие этому хэшу.

Когда вы хотите найти некоторый текст в таблице, то по нему вычисляется хэш (скажем некоторое значение 129827172) и ищется именно это значения за O(log(N))время, когда запись находится, то смотрится куда она ссылается и дальше уже получается доступ к данным

Comment: спасибо большое, сейчас буду подробнее разбираться

Comment: А если часть вычисленного хэша использовать как номер блока в файле, то получим (при разряженной таблице) в основном константное время...

Comment: @avp, опять же - если диапазон хэшей небольшой, то мы тоже получаем константное время - например какое-нибудь CRC16 даст 64000 ячейки только, что терпимо

Comment: @Zhihar, традиционно берется остаток от деления хэша на размер таблицы (при этом желательно, чтобы размер таблицы был простым числом, что обеспечивает равномерное рассеивание)

Comment: @avp, а.. ок, вообще всегда думал, что нормальный хэш (главное требование к хэшу) и так даёт равномерное рассеивание, на счет простых чисел - да, хорошее применение, аналогично тому как у звездочек простое кол-во зубцов для равномерного износа - следствие того, что `n mod p` проходит по всем остаткам от 0 до p-1